# Passing a bound variable to ng-click for dynamic click handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following dom.

```
   <td grid-item ng-repeat='col in columnDefs' ng-click="actions[col.field]"></td>
```

This is wrapped in a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').
directive('gridItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'views/grid_item.html',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$eval(element.attr('ng-click'))) {
                element.addClass('clickable');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

For clarity: 
actions is an Object of the format:

```
   {some_column: '', some_other_column: 'myFunction(arguments)', some_third_column: 'myOtherFunction(arguments)'}
```

and `col.field` will be `some_column`, `some_other_column`, etc depending on the particular iteration

This binds fine and adds the clickable class to the elements where ng-click is non-blank.

However, the method on the controller is never called. Why is this? And how can I bind dynamically to a function based off a string representation?

The string representation of activity[col.field] (in this case) is: `fetch('activity', $parent.$index)`.

The controller is certainly in scope as it is defined through the `controller:` key on a parent directive with (unsure if this is relevant) isolate scope.

NOTE: I have found a way to hack it to work,

```
      element.on('click', function(){
        scope.$eval(scope.$eval(attrs.ngClick));
      });
```

obviously, that is a less then ideal solution...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change `actions[col.field]` to `actions(col.field)`. This is my test code for your directive:

```
<div lang="en" ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
        <td grid-item ng-repeat='col in columnDefs' ng-click="actions(col.field)"></td>
    </table>
</div>

app.directive('gridItem', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div>blah</div>',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$eval(element.attr('ng-click'))) {
                element.addClass('clickable');
            }
        }
    };
});

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.columnDefs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    $scope.actions = function (field) {
        console.log(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clearer. actions is a hash. I've edited my question to reflect this.